# JavaScript Date Formats

Tags: javascript

Currently I'm getting below result when I'm entering the mm/dd and using the below code

```
var d = new Date("10/11");
```

Result:
Thu Oct 11 2001 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

But I would like to get mm/dd/yyyy(current year default) like below

Thu Oct 11 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

Please assist.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this statement in your code.

var d = new Date("2020,10,11");